# running powershell via cygwin

Tags: powershell, cygwin

Running this command from a cygwin window fails because powershell cant find object, "Get-EventLog":

```
 echo "\n" | powershell.exe Get-EventLog System | Where-Object { $_.EventID -match "6009" }
```

The Get-EveneLog Systerm query work just fine from a Powershell console so I know it's not a syntax issue. And I have included the powershell path.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

After a brief trial and error session I discovered that if the query is encased in single quotes it will work :

```
powershell.exe 'Get-EventLog System | Where-Object { $_.EventID -match "6009" }'
```

Answer (score 0):

powershell.exe -command 'Get-EventLog System | Where-Object { $_.EventID -match "6009" }'